# Pointer to member of a typename

Tags: c++, templates, typename, pointer-to-member, gcc4.7

Consider this:

```
template < typename VectorType >
void ff()
{
    // This passes.
    typedef typename VectorType::value_type VV;
    typedef int VV::* MM;

    // This FAILS!??
    typedef int typename VectorType::value_type::* MMM;
}
```

Why the second fails and what is the correct way to get the desired typedef in one typedef statement?

My compiler is the GCC-4.7.2.

Comment: Does it work as `typedef int VectorType::value_type::* MMM`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I believe you should turn this to an answer, the `typename` is clearly superfluous there (there's no identifier to the right of `::`).

Comment: @Angew: It is not merely *superfluous*. It is incorrect to use `typename` there.

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh sure :) Please turn it into answer.

Comment: I was just guessing :-) This looked like one of those situations where "a typename is expected", so no disambiguation is needed. But I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you have a `typename` where it shouldn't be:

```
typedef int typename VectorType::value_type::* MMM;
```

should be just:

```
typedef int VectorType::value_type::* MMM;
```

`typename` is used when you have `a::b` inside a template, `a` depends on template parameters and `b` is a type. In that case, you have to use `typename a::b` to communicate this fact to the compiler.

On the other hand, you're doing `a::b::*`, which is a clear indicator that `b` must be a type, so `typename` cannot be used here.